# Can't mount disc image file. The Disc Image File is Corrupted

Tags: recovery-mode

I want to root my phone. So i tried many times with the platform tools to install twrp which is pitch black recovery in my tecno in 1 pro phone. Here is the Link of the recovery https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=1395089523397967061. When i flash recovery it shows me cant mount the file. The recovery is an unofficial twrp. I really need is solution. Please reply me if you have solution

Comment: The RAR file you have downloaded is just the "transport container" Have you unpacked the download using unrar/WinRAR before flashing it? If you do so you find the `recovery.img` that can be flashed.

Comment: `adb pull /tmp/recovery.log`

Comment: Yes i extracted it but every img file occur the same problem